# Disable git config url in spring cloud

Tags: spring, git, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I need to disable git configs or any other version control service in the spring-cloud config, Can Anyone suggest how to do this?

```
cloud:
    config:
      server:
         git:
          uri:
```

I don't need any such configurations

Thanks in Advance

Comment: By default you have to enable git or svn, they aren't active without any configuration. If you mean IDE completion of the properties, there's nothing to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: false
      override-none: true
```